# Can I use the blockchain as a web server?

Tags: blockchain, dapps

Is it possible to use the blockchain as "web server"?

Even if a web app stores all data per smart contracts on the blockchain I still need a central server to get the web app initially. Is there an approach to serve HTML & co. direct from the blockchain like a central web server does it or is this not possible?

I have the following use case: Let's say I deploy web components on my server. Everyone can use my web components now in there app. If I decide to shut down my server or my server is temporary not available, all apps which are dependent on my components are not working anymore. If I deploy my web components on the blockchain (if possible) this could never happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Swarm,

Swarm is a distributed storage platform and content distribution service: 
take a look here https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

Whisper: for encrypted messaging, take a look here https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Whisper

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot serve html/js/css from Ethereum blockchain.

What you can do is :

1. Deploy business logic as Dapp. This logic is available as an http endpoint
2. Deploy Static files (html / css etc) on some CDN (Like S3 or other)

This way, Html is always available and uses blockchain for business logic + data persistence.